# IRepository vs ISession

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, repository, castle-windsor

I have some Repository. Work with them is realized through an interface `IRepository`. 
In [sample project](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Windsor-tutorial-ASP-NET-MVC-3-application-To-be-Seen.ashx) `HomeController` constructor realized with ISession. When I wrote this:

```
public class TestingController : Controller
{
    private ISession session;

    public TestingController(ISession session)
    {
        this.session = session;
    }
//Some code here with this.session
}
```

It working well. When I decided to use `IRepository`:

```
public class TestingController : Controller
{
    private IRepository repository;

    public TestingController(IRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }
//Some code here with this.repository
}
```

It doesn't work in this method of other class `WindsorControllerFactory`:

```
protected override IController GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType == null)
        {
            throw new HttpException(404, string.Format("The controller for path {0} culd not found!", requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Path));
        }

        return (IController)this.kernel.Resolve(controllerType);
    }
```

I have exception

> Can't create component 'MvcApplication1.Controllers.ResultsController' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.
>
> 'MvcApplication1.Controllers.ResultsController' is waiting for the
>   following dependencies:
>   - Service 'dal.Repository.IRepository' which was not registered.

How to solve it?

P.S. Assembly `dal.Repository` is working. If I write everywhere `new dal.Repository.Repository()` instead of `this.repository` - it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you missing the binding for `IRepository`.

You have to have concrete class that would implement `IRepository` interface, say `MyRepository`. Then you should configure Windsor, to understand what the `IRepository` is about.

Something like,

```
container.Register(Component.For<IRepository>().ImplementedBy<MyRepository>());
```

Answer (score 0):

I able to resolve the same issue by following this [Documentation](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/mvc-tutorial-part-9-diagnosing-missing-dependency-issues.md)

and another thing is if we download new version for this project from github we will not see this expcetion [Link](https://github.com/kkozmic/ToBeSeen)